# How I Can insert images on Captured video in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I captured video using cv2.VideoCapured and display. Captured Video display on same time not saved. How I can insert image on this captured video for display on same time.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please clarify your video source, is it a video file or from a camera? If your source is video file, why you need to save while displaying it? Or do you want to save the video obtained by camera?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want to add image directly to video frames at a certain x,y location without doing any color blending or image transparency. you can use the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cv2

# load the overlay image. size should be smaller than video frame size
img = cv2.imread('logo.png')

# Get Image dimensions
img_height, img_width, _ = img.shape

# Start Capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Get frame dimensions
frame_width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
frame_height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )

# Print dimensions
print('image dimensions (HxW):',img_height,"x",img_width)
print('frame dimensions (HxW):',int(frame_height),"x",int(frame_width))

# Decide X,Y location of overlay image inside video frame. 
# following should be valid:
#   * image dimensions must be smaller than frame dimensions
#   * x+img_width <= frame_width
#   * y+img_height <= frame_height
# otherwise you can resize image as part of your code if required

x = 50
y = 50

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # add image to frame
    frame[ y:y+img_height , x:x+img_width ] = img

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    # Exit if ESC key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please give more details if my assumption was wrong.

Comment: I changed your code a little bit and did not worked, If I send my github reposity link here then would you look at it?

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL yes pls send let me see it and what error you get